# What can I do to directly access any system without having to log in?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, user-accounts, lan

I have a issue that may be in local area connection or DNS on server.

I have a local area network with one server and 5 systems. I have installed the DNS on server to manage the users. now issue is that when I want to access any other system from one system then some times it goes to connect but some times a popup box is open as login prompt. After enter the username and password, it goes to connect.

I don't want to this things. I want to directly access any system without login prompt.

Is there any solution for remove this issue?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "access any other system". There are many ways to access a system.

Comment: by using system ip in run command like "\\10.0.0.98" or by direct in network place

Comment: What operating systems are involved?

Comment: XP on all systems and windows server 2003 on server

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here - firstly, you can add a domain controller to your network (DNS on its own doesn't maintain user accounts), and join all of your computers to the domain.  Then you can use your domain account to access all of the computers, and the password will always be synchronised.  This might be overkill on a small network, though.

Secondly - and more simply - just keep your username and password the same across all the computers.  That way, you should be able to connect without re-entering your password, even if the computers are in different domains, or not in a domain at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply. According to your first solution, I am following that architecture and maintain the user account in domain controller. In your second solution, I can't use same all user name and password on lan .

Comment: Ok - so you have: Machine1, Machine2 - and DOMAINCONTROLLER.  Are machine1 and machine2 joined to the domain of DOMAINCONTROLLER?  If not, they won't be able to authenticate you using your domain account.  At a minimum you need the target computer to be joined to the domain, and to be logged on with the domain account on the computer from which you're trying to connect (or logged on with a local account that has the same username and password as the domain account).

Comment: yes I already joined the all machines on domain controller and logged in by domain account on each computer but issue is same

Comment: I would take a look at the security logs on the target computer (where you're connecting to) when this happens, to look for any failure events.  See what's in there.

Comment: Just another thought - you might need to disable caching on the profiles share: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842007